# SQL query on sap b1 9.0

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    T0.CardCode'CUSTOMER CODE',
    T0.CardName 'CUSTOMER NAME',
    T0.[ProjectCod]'Project',   
    T0.[CntctPrsn]'CONTACT PERSON',
    T0.[MailBuildi]'ADDRESS',T0.[MailBlock]'ADDRESS1',
    T0.[Cellular]'MOBILE',  
    T0.[E_Mail]'EMAIL',
    T1.[U_TINNUMBER]'TIN NUMBER',
    T2.[TaxId0]'PAN NUMBER',
    T2.[ECCNo]'ECC'
FROM 
    [dbo].[OCRD] T0 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CRD1] T1 ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode] 
INNER JOIN 
    CRD7 T2 ON T0.[CardCode] = T2.[CardCode]  
WHERE 
    T0.CardType = 'C'
```

On output same row is repeating 6 times please help

Comment: This will depend on your database design. You can either add 'distinct' or include a 'group by' to deal with the so called duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that one of the three tables has 6 rows with the same `CardCode` value.

You can do one of the two (depends on the datamodel and your desired output).

1. Use more strict join (add another condition to the join)
     (e.g. `JOIN [dbo].[CRD1] T1 ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode] **AND T1.Valid = 1**`)
2. Add DISTINCT to the SELECT.
      (e.g. `SELECT **DISTINCT** T0.CardCode'CUSTOMER CODE`)

Comment: Can you please post how to use use distinct to my query because still not able to remove repeatition

Comment: If DISTINCT doesn't give you work, then you have different values in the columns. Look at the values and try to find the reason why they're there. I think my first idea would work better in this case.